# Print the content of tablelayoutpanel after clicking a button C#

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

```
private void bt_saveImage_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)   
{
   using (Bitmap printImage = new Bitmap(tlp.Width, tlp.Height))
   {
       tlp.DrawToBitmap(printImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, printImage.Width, printImage.Height));                   
       printImage.Save( "C:/image.jpg",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
   }              
   throw new System.NotImplementedException();       
}
```

I have error saying "ExternalException is unhanlered; A generic error occurred in GDI+." on 
    `"printImage.Save( "C:/image.jpg",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)`"

Thanks for help!

Comment: Sounds like not disposed reference of Bitmap or something else... Do you have any other code which access C:/image.jpg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use @ before "C:\image.jpg"

```
printImage.Save( @"C:\image.jpg",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

**OR**

Use "\\" in the location

```
printImage.Save( "C:\\image.jpg",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

Comment: you are creating a blank image having dimension of tableLayoutPanel.

Comment: oh, yes, you r right. Do you know how to print the content of tlp? Thanks a lot!

Comment: i thought drawtoBitmap send the content of tableLayoutPanel to image.